# Distributed Computing With XML-RPC Python

Tags: python, xml, distributed-computing, xml-rpc

Alright, here is a project I am running into issues with. I have the code written up, but it's running into issues. Frankly, I'm not even sure I connected the two files I had to use correctly so if someone could take a gander and help me determine what's wrong, I'd be glad for the assistance. Here are the instructions/hints.

> Common tasks in distributed computing applications often require the
> ability of one computer to be able to remotely invoke a procedure on
> another computer in the distributed system. This assignment introduces
> this idea further using XML-RPC and Python.
>
> XML-RPC is a protocol used to call procedures, (i.e. methods or
> functions) by one computer (client) on another computer (server). Its
> name results from fact that XML is used to encode the procedure calls.
> The means used to transport the XML from the client to the server is
> HTTP. While Python has built-in support for this functionality, it is
> important to note that support is not limited to Python but extends to
> most high level languagesadd. This is inherent in the design since the
> encoding is generic XML and transport is HTTP.
>
> Finally, there are many ways to implement such functionality. For
> Python, while outside the scope of this course, the interested reader
> should explore projects such as Pyro, RPyC, and Fabric.
>
> XML-RPC’s implementation in Python is found in the xmlrpc package. In
> this package, the required modules are xmlrpc.client and
> xmlrpc.server.
>
> **Assignment**
>
> This assignment requires you to develop two Python programs. One is a
> client, the other is the server.
>
> **Server**
> The server should “register” x procedures that the client will
> be able to call. It will then bind to the address “localhost” and port
> 8000. This is the address and port that the server will listen to for requests. Note that if you have binding errors, you may use another
> port as your computer may have an application that is using 8000. Most
> of the time, however, this will work. Your server invocation must be
> in the following form:
>
> python server.py localhost 8000
>
> These procedures to be supported are as follows: name – returns the
> name of the server which is passed on the commandline during server
> invocation help – returns a list of procedures that the server
> supports servertime – returns the current time at the server in 24
> hour format. I.e. 13:00:01 add(x,y) – returns the sum of x and y
> sub(x,y) – returns x – y mult(x,y) – returns x * y div(x,y) – returns
> x/y (be sure to handle the divid by 0 scenario)
>
> **Client**
> The client is to connect to the server using the server’s
> address and the port that the server is listening on (see above). It
> then will exercise each of the supported procedures using the values 8
> and 6 for the values x and y respectively. Your client invocation must
> be in the following form:
>
> python client.py host_address host_port 8 6
>
> where host_address and host_port are the address and port that the
> server is listening on. If you are using a single computer for server
> and client computers just use “localhost” for the address and the port
> used above. The 8 and the 6 are the values for x and y.
>
> Example Output Of Client:
>
> 8 * 6 is 48.0 8 / 6 is 1.3333333333333333 8 + 6 is 14.0 8 - 6 is 2.0 8
> / 0 is Infinity 13:50:22

I will give the code of both files so that someone might be able to help with it. It's more the Server.py file having issues than the Client.py file, but I will post both anyways.

**Server.py**

```
import sys
import time
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

argumentList = sys.argv
hostAddress = argumentList[1]
port = argumentList[2]
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((hostAddress, int(port)))


def addition(x, y):
    return x + y


def subtraction(x, y):
    return x - y


def multiplication(x, y):
    return x * y


def division(x, y):
    try:
        return x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "To Infinity and Beyond! Whee!"


def name():
    return hostAddress


def helpMe():
    return server.systemListMethods()


def serverTime():
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


server.register_function(helpMe)
server.register_function(addition)
server.register_function(serverTime)
server.register_function(subtraction)
server.register_function(multiplication)
server.register_function(division)
server.serve_forever()
```

*Errors/Warnings Screenshot*
[image]

**Client.py**

```
import xmlrpc.client
import sys

argumentsList = sys.argv
hostAddress = argumentsList[1]
hostPort = argumentsList[2]

URI = "http://" + hostAddress + ":" + hostPort

num1 = int(argumentsList[3])
num2 = int(argumentsList[4])
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(URI)

print('{} + {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.add(num1, num2)))
print('{} - {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.sub(num1, num2)))
print('{} * {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.mul(num1, num2)))
print('{} / {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.div(num1, num2)))
print(proxy.name())
print(proxy.help())
print(proxy.serverTime())
```

Any assistance with this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There was many bugs in both your server.py and client.py. I rewrote the files with bug corrected.

**server.py:**

```
import sys
import time
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

argumentList = sys.argv
hostAddress = '0.0.0.0'
port = '12345'
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer((hostAddress, int(port)))

def addition(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtraction(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiplication(x, y):
    return x * y

def division(x, y):
    try:
        return x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "To Infinity and Beyond! Whee!"

def name():
    return hostAddress
 
def helpMe():
    return server.system_listMethods()

def serverTime():
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

server.register_function(name)
server.register_function(helpMe)
server.register_function(addition)
server.register_function(serverTime)
server.register_function(subtraction)
server.register_function(multiplication)
server.register_function(division)
server.serve_forever()
```

**client.py**

```
import xmlrpc.client
import sys

argumentsList = sys.argv
hostAddress = '127.0.0.1'
hostPort = '12345'

URI = "http://" + hostAddress + ":" + hostPort

num1 = int('7')
num2 = int('5')
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(URI)

print('{} + {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.addition(num1, num2)))
print('{} - {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.subtraction(num1, num2)))
print('{} * {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.multiplication(num1, num2)))
print('{} / {} is {}'.format(num1, num2, proxy.division(num1, num2)))
print(proxy.name())
print(proxy.helpMe())
print(proxy.serverTime())
```

Good luck